# ¿Cómo se logra ocultar parte del email en ASP.NET? C*****reo25@ejemplo.com

Tags: c#, asp.net

Saludos,
¿Cómo se logra que un correo electrónico o cualquier otro campo oculte con * (asteriscos parte de la palabra)?
Por ejemplo así llega el siguiente correo.
[image: ejemplo]

.CS del envío de correo

```
 string username = string.Empty;
        string password = string.Empty;
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Web2017_test"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Username, [Password] FROM Users WHERE Email = @Email"))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        username = sdr["Username"].ToString();
                        password = sdr["Password"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage("webmaster@myFirstWeb.com", txtEmail.Text.Trim());

            mailMsg.Subject = "Su usuario es";
            string body = "Cuenta My Web Page<br />";
            body += string.Format("<br /><br />Su usuario es: <strong>{0:}</strong>.<br /><br />", username);
            body += "<p>haz clic en el siguiente enlace para iniciar sesión<br />&raquo;<a href='http://localhost/login.aspx'>http://localhost/login.aspx</a></p>";
            body += "Si no reconoce la actividad en está cuenta, puede enviarnos un correo electrónico indicando que no es usted quien ha solicitado esta información.";

            mailMsg.Body = body;
            mailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient servidor = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            servidor.Port = 587;
            servidor.EnableSsl = true;
            servidor.Send(mailMsg);

            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lblMessage.Text = "El nombre de usuario solicitado se ha enviado a su cuenta de correo.";
            lblMessage.Font.Size = 15;
            Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "5; url=forgotUser.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lblMessage.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lblMessage.Text = "<strong>Atención!</strong>* La dirección de correo que ingresó no se encuentra registrada.";
            lblMessage.Font.Size = 10;
        }
```

Comment: En el ejemplo que nos pones no se envia el email en ningun sitio no? Que campo querrias ocultar con `*`?

Comment: Si en el ejemplo del .CS envía un correo a la dirección de correo del mismo usuario. y por ejemplo tengo: micorreo@gmail.com >> m*****eo@gmail.com

Comment: Me refiero a que se envía el `usuario` en el cuerpo del correo, no la direccion de correo. Es ese el que quisieras ocultar?

Comment: Si en este caso sí, solo como ejemplo y de ahí lo aplicaré al correo, que aun no lo he creado. XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay muchas posibles maneras de hacer lo que quieres. Yo te doy solo una posibilidad:

```
string usuario = "ejemplo123@ejemplo.com";
string[] separada = usuario.Split('@');
int inicio = 1; //Caracteres al inicio de la cadena que dejamos visibles
int final = 3; //Caracteres al final de la cadena que dejamos visibles
int longitud;
if (separada[0].Length > inicio+final)
    longitud = separada[0].Length - final - inicio;
else
    longitud = 1;

separada[0] = separada[0].Remove(inicio, longitud).Insert(inicio, new string('*', longitud));
usuario = String.Join( "@",separada);
```

Este código con `"ejemplo123@ejemplo.com"` da como salida `"e******123@ejemplo.com"`. Probablemente se puede optimizar mas pero esto es sólo para que veas una posibilidad y lo ajustes a tus necesidades.

Comment: Solucionado: Tal cual mi hermano así es lo que estaba planeando, muchas gracias!!!

Comment: esto falla para el correo poco@ejemplo.com..

Comment: Ya empezamos XD A que llamas "fallar"?  Daría 'p*co@ejemplo.com' si no me equivoco (ahora no puedo probarlo)

Comment: separada[0].Length >= inicio+final; length = 4 = inicio + final = 4.. no entra ;)

Comment: igual sabes que te quiero no?? @Pikoh

Comment: Pq me hiciste dudar. Ahora(que es como estaba al principio) no fallaba ;)

Comment: Volver loco me quieres @gbianchi

Comment: Ahora que pienso,donde si fallaría es si el usuario solo tiene un caracter y se pone `inicio>0` ,mañana lo reviso. Al final @gbianchi tenía razon ;)